# Include a file in C with VsCodium and WSL

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, wsl-2, vscodium

I'm trying to include a custom file into my program in C, and it compiles ok. However, VsCodium keeps complaining about "Squiggles" and "includePath" (don't know what that means), actually, I don't know precisely how to configure the ".vscode/c_cpp_properties.json" file as I am using WSL to compile the code and VsCodium is installed on Windows.

Here is the line:

```c
#include "./types.h"
// #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (\\wsl$\Arch\home\{*}\{*}\{*}.c).C/C++(1696)
// cannot open source file "./types.h"
```

What should I do? It's a little annoying although it's working

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File`->`Preferences`->`Settings`.

**Optional**: Switch to the Workspace tab (if you only want this to take effect on the current workspace).

In the search box, type in `c_cpp include path` or something similar.

Find the `C_Cpp->Default: Include path` field, then click Add item.

Enter your include path which contains the file you want to include.

Comment: Note that being on WSL and VSCodium doesn't matter. This process is the same for all platforms and builds of VS Code.

Comment: The problem is, how should I specify my WSL folder/file path, I tried "types.h", "${workspaceFolder}/types.h", "\\wsl$\Arch\home\username\folder\types.h", "\\wsl$\Arch\home\username\folder\". I also have a c_cpp_properties.json file which contains "${workspaceFolder}/**" in the `includePath` property; and none of them worked...

Comment: `${workspaceFolder}/include-folder` should work.

Comment: Do you mean to change 'include-folder' to the folder name? No, it didn't work at all.
I decided to disable these warnings for now `"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"`

Comment: Yes, the `include-folder` is the folder which contains the header.